# How to get sub array that has maximum sum of all its items

Tags: c#

My test is to solve this following problem:
A zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
Write a solution to find out the sub array of A, which contains consequent items that has the maximum sum of all its items.

Example:

- `A = [2, -1, 3, -3, 4, -9, 10, -3, 4, -4, -7, 2, 8]`. The answer is `[10, -3, 4]`
- `A = [3, 2, -5, 7, 4, -8, 3, -5, 2, 4, -2, 4]`. The answer is `[7, 4]`
- `A = [-2, 5, 3, 6, -1,-5]`. The answer is `[-2, 5, 3, 6]`.

Please help me to give me the way to resolve it.

Comment: what have you done to resolve it?

Comment: Posting a homework ? How do you expect to learn how to solve a problem if we just posted the answer ? This can be solved in dozens of ways. What have you tried ? What went wrong ? Where have you stopped ?

Comment: I  have still not found a solution to resolve it. Please guide me the ideal to resolve it.

Comment: @user1186850 Can you solve this using your eyes without writing code ? If yes, write a series of pseudo code steps using English (Forget C#).  If you can do that, then you're 95% the way into your answer. Hint: Start scanning sequential items and store the sum of each combination.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Have a look at point 3. Show some effort and you will receive help. On a side note: start accepting answers (even for your old but evidently answered questions it is not too late to do so)!

Comment: In the last example, why is -2 part of the subarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly, what you need to do is to traverse the array and check for the maximum value of the sum of elements. Once you have found the max sum, you have the last element of your resulting subarray.
Once you have found the max element, you need to traverse back and do the same in order to find the sub array with maximum sum of elements.

```
int iNewTopHigh = 0;
int iNewTopLow  = 0;
int iIndNewTopHigh = 0;
int iIndNewTopLow  = 0;
int iSumHigh   = 0;
int iSumLow    = 0;

int[] iArr  =  {2, -1, 3, -3, 4, -9, 10, -3, 4, -4, -7, 2, 8};
               //{3, 2, -5, 7, 4, -8, 3, -5, 2, 4, -2, 4};
               //{-2, 5, 3, 6, -1,-5};
//Get the top 
for(int i = 0; i < iArr.Length; i++){   
    iSumHigh += iArr[i];
    if(iSumHigh > iNewTopHigh){ 
      iIndNewTopHigh = i;
      iNewTopHigh = iSumHigh;             
    }           
}
//Get the bottom
for(int i = iIndNewTopHigh; i != 0; i--){
    iSumLow += iArr[i];
    if(iSumLow > iNewTopLow){
       iIndNewTopLow = i;
       iNewTopLow = iSumLow;
    }
}
//Print results
for(int i = iIndNewTopLow ; i <= iIndNewTopHigh; i++){
    Console.Write(iArr[i] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It run faster my nested loop.